# Verifying the data format in columns for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of strings representing numbers (integers and floats).

I want to implement a validation to make sure the strings in certain columns only represent integers.

Here is a dataframe containing two columns, with header `str as ints` and `str as double`, representing integers and floats in string format.

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list elements
data = ['10','20','30','40','50','60']

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['str as ints'])
df['str as double'] = ['10.0', '20.0', '30.0', '40.0', '50.0', '60.0']
```

Here is a function I wrote that checks for the radix in the string to determine whether it is an integer or float.

```
def includes_dot(s):
    return '.' in s
```

I want to see if I can use the apply function on this dataframe, or do I need to write another function where I pass in the name of the dataframe and the list of column headers and then call `includes_dot` like this:

```
def check_df(df, lst):
    for val in lst:
        apply(df[val]...?)
    # then print out the results if certain columns fail the check
```

Or if there are better ways to do this problem altogether.

The expected output is a list of column headers that fails the criteria: if I have a list `['str as ints', 'str as double']`, then `str as double` should be printed because that column does not contain all integers.

Comment: Could you try this, `df['str as double'].str.contains('.')`?

Comment: I am unclear as to what the objective of the ```check_df``` function is?  Do you want to identify rows where a column entry fails to include a '.'?  Do you want to filter out rows where a column contains a '.'? Please clarify your question and possibly include an example of your expected output using the ```check_df``` function.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah The reason that doesn't work is `str.contains` defaults to using regex, so you either have to specify `regex=False` or make it regex compatible.

Comment: @BeRT2me - The above suggested code indeed works. please have a look at the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: @MohamedThasinah `df['str as ints'].str.contains('.')` also returns all Trues... it does in fact NOT WORK. regex `.` is the wildcard.

Comment: Now I got your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in df:
    if df[col].str.contains('\.').any():
        print(col, "contains a '.'")
```